# Why is there no Main-Class attribute in generated manifest?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a build.sbt file that includes the assembly plugin.  Up until the most recent build, the Main-Class attribute was being included in the assembled far jar, but all of a sudden, this is no longer the case.

When I attempt to run the jar, I get the inimitable:

```
no main manifest attribute, in ./target/scala-2.10/foo-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but using run from the sbt console, works fine.

My build.sbt currently looks like this (the mainClass in assembly added in an attempt to force indicate to the assembly plugin that it really should include, though I noticed in the plugin source code, it looks like it's checking the one specified for run anyway).

```
import AssemblyKeys._

name := "foo"

version := "0.3.0-SNAPSHOT"

organization := "com.mycompany.myproduct"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("ProcessRelogger")

mainClass in assembly := Some("ProcessRelogger")

assemblySettings

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "1.9.2" % "test",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.9",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.4",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.3",
  "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "3.3.4",
  "org.scalaz" % "scalaz-core_2.10" % "7.0.6",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
  "com.escalatesoft.subcut" %% "subcut" % "2.0"
)
```

and when I unzip the jar file, and check META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, there's no Main-Class: attribute included.

Comment: Silly question - are there multiple mains in Processrelogger?

Comment: My first guess would be to try FQDN instead of just class name.

Comment: What's the version of sbt-assembly?

Comment: Using 0.11.2 of sbt-assembly, and there aren't multiple mains in ProcessRelogger, and it is the FQDN, it's in the root package.

Comment: Could you remove the two `mainClass` lines and start over? Can you do `show compile:run::mainClass` afterwards and include it to the question? Can you also execute `assembly` and then `last-grep` with the name of the main class? Add the outputs to the question.

Comment: I have discovered another thing, the system has TWO app classes that are used in different situations.  I reproduced the test setup given below, and if I put in a mainClass := Some("Thing") where the class does not exist, it does not fail, but simply picks the class that is the app?!

Comment: > show compile:run::mainClass
[info] Some(ProcessRelogger)

Comment: and grepping for the main class on assembly shows a whole lot of bupkiss

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt to reproduce the issue with the latest version of [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) 0.11.2.

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.7-M3
```

**project/assembly.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

**build.sbt**

```
import AssemblyKeys._

assemblySettings

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"
```

**src/main/scala/Main.scala**

```
object HelloApp extends App {
  println("Hello")
}
```

With all the files above in a single project:

```
> about
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-assembly/}sbt-assembly...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] This is sbt 0.13.7-M3
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-assembly/}sbt-assembly 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.2
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin, net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin, com.github.tototoshi.sbt.musical.Plugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin, sbtassembly.Plugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4

> assembly
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-assembly/}sbt-assembly...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-assembly/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Including: scala-library-2.11.2.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[info] SHA-1: a5c09d7626fe19f4e3cd98d709966a77f127b048
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-assembly/target/scala-2.11/sbt-assembly-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Oct 8, 2014 9:27:41 AM

> eval "unzip -p target/scala-2.11/sbt-assembly-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" !
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: sbt-assembly
Implementation-Version: 0.1-SNAPSHOT
Specification-Vendor: default
Specification-Title: sbt-assembly
Implementation-Vendor-Id: default
Specification-Version: 0.1-SNAPSHOT
Main-Class: HelloApp
Implementation-Vendor: default

[info] ans: Int = 0
```

Comment: Indeed - this used to work fine, and then it stopped working fine, and I can't seem to figure out what changed that might have that effect.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the "why" for the original question, but as other comments mentioned this can happen if you introduced another `main` (e.g. including indirectly through another object).

So you can explicitly define it for example in your build.sbt:

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("path.to.intended.Main")  // object with main
```

Comment: Not sure how this is different than what's given in the build.sbt above?

Answer (score 0):

Try comment out mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("ProcessRelogger")

`]$ sbt clean assembly
]$ java -jar target/xxx.jar`